# Access to WebApi Data from ASP

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp-classic

I have an old application written using ASP. Is it possible to retrieve data from a Web API (JSON) with classic ASP, not ASP.NET technology?

Comment: Can you share more information about what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Someone wrote a class for processing JSON data at http://www.aspjson.com/, I've used it once before and it worked nicely.